# Delete Element from XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have been trying to delete the **structuredBody** element (which is within a component element) within the [following Document](https://gitlab.com/elga-gmbh/cda-beispielbefunde/-/blob/master/Basisleitf%C3%A4den_(2.06.2)/ELGA-023-Entlassungsbrief_aerztlich_EIS-FullSupport.xml), but my code seems to not work.

The structure of the XML source file simplified:

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
...
  <component>
    <structuredBody>
    ...
    ...
    </structuredBody>
  </component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import objectify, etree

cda_tree = etree.parse('ELGA-023-Entlassungsbrief_aerztlich_EIS-FullSupport.xml')
cda_root = cda_tree.getroot()
for e in cda_root: 
    ET.register_namespace("", "urn:hl7-org:v3")

for node in cda_tree.xpath('//component/structuredBody'):
    node.getparent().remove(node)

cda_tree.write('newXML.xml')
```

Whenever I run the code, the newXML.xml file still has the structuredBody element.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Include a well-formed snippet of the XML as part of your question. The XML file you linked to also contains a lot of irrelevant data which have no bearing on your question.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I provided also the simplified structure of the xml file, hope this helps

Comment: Why are you importing both `lxml` and `xml.etree`?

Comment: @larsks I'm using ET to delete the namespaces which are added automatically by the .parse function and with etree I'm trying to delete the structuredBody element

Comment: But you're *not* using `ET`. You're using `lxml`, so you need to manage namespace the way `lxml` expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your most recent edit, I think you'll find the problem is that your `for` loop isn't matching any nodes. Your document doesn't contain any elements named `component` or `structuredBody`. The `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"` declaration on the root element mean that all elements in the document exist by default in that particular namespace, so you need to use that namespace when matching elements:

```
from lxml import objectify, etree

cda_tree = etree.parse('data.xml')
cda_root = cda_tree.getroot()

ns = {
    'hl7': 'urn:hl7-org:v3',
}

for node in cda_tree.xpath('//hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody', namespaces=ns):
    node.getparent().remove(node)

cda_tree.write('newXML.xml')
```

With the above code, if the input looks like this:

```
<ClinicalDocument
    xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <component>
    <structuredBody>
    ...
    ...
    </structuredBody>
  </component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

The output looks like:

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <component>
    </component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @larsks, now it is deleting the structuredBody element and the namespaces are handled much better now. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: If this answer has resolved your problem, consider clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer in order to mark it as "accepted".